# Integrating a particular tensor

Tags: integration, tensors

I have a tensor defined by $T_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}x_k$, and I want to find $\int_ST_{ij}dS$, where S is the surface of the unit sphere.

I'm having some problems because I really don't know what integrating a tensor is. I'm also confused about what the surface integral is doing, since the dS is scalar not a vector (i.e. $ndS$ )

If I work in Cartesians I think $x_k$ is the normal to the sphere, but that has led to confusion because I think I should be working in sphericals.

Even integrating $\delta_{ij}$ has confused me, because of the scalar surface element.

Any help would be really really appreciated :)

Comment: Can you also where you see this notation?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Where did you see this notation (note, paper....?)

Comment: http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/Vector_Calculus/VC_2014-15_glt.pdf , sheet 4 question 7

Comment: Well, from the notation I would guess that it is nothing but integrating each component of $T_{ij}$ term by term on $S$.

Comment: But what does integrating on S mean here? E.g. What would $\int_SxdS$ be?

Comment: I know how to do surface integrals with a vector surface element dS, but the scalar element is confusing

Comment: That would be a vector with the $i$-th component given by $\int_S x_i dS$.

Comment: And how would I compute that surface integral?

Comment: In general if you want to calculate $\int_S f(x) dS$, you have to find out a parametrization for $S$, (that is a mapping $F: U \to S$) and then do the calculation on $U$. But in this special case where your function is $x_i$ and $S$ is the unit sphere, you can use the fact that $x_i$ is an "odd" function on $S$, so the integral is zero.

Comment: What book/notes are you using? I am not 100% sure that my interpretation is correct.

Comment: https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_L/vector_calculus.pdf , the tensor section. They're Dexter Chua's notes

Comment: It's in p.74. Though the definition is not given, the wording in there convinced me that my interpretation is correct.